# store operator as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

within a loop I have this

```
if(id < arr.length - 1 && a != null){
//lots of thing here
}
```

Can I store the operator `id < arr.length - 1` into a variable? I don't want to have redundant code using else for above statement.

can I do like this ?

```
var check = a == true ? id < arr.length - 1 : false;
```

Comment: Have you tried to see if it works? If not, what error do you get?

Comment: If I understand you correct, you need to store the **result** of (comparison) operator, not operator itself

Comment: var check = (a === true && (id < arr.length - 1) ? true : false;

but arr and id need to be accessible.

Comment: `length` is a property, so asking for it is probably going to be so fast that storing the value of it in a variable won't make much difference. Unless you're calling `arr.length` a few million times, this is micro-optimisation

Comment: Of course, storing it is as easy as `var b = id < arr.length - 1`, the question then becomes wether or not you're modifying the array within the loop

Comment: Do you want to store the `expression` or the `result of evaluating it`? It's unclear what your question really is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to store the condition (not operator).

```
// (within a loop)
var first_condition = id < arr.length - 1; // stored as true or false (boolean)
var second_condition = a !== null; // note the !== NOT !=

if ( first_condition && second_condition ) {
    // lots of thing here
}
```

Although if you meant redundant as in `else if`s with same condition, you can do nested `if` instead.

```
if ( first_condition ) {
    if ( second_condition ) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var condition_check=(id < arr.length - 1) && a !== null;
if (condition_ckeck){
    //lots of things will happen
}
```